# Adding List of Maps to Maps with separate key - Dart

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of `Map()` fetched from Firebase i.e `_rewardMapList`. Every Map() in `_rewardMapList` contains `matchkey: xyz`. After extracting the `matchkey` from each Map in `_rewardMapList`. I want to add all the Maps in `_rewardMapList` with respective Keys extracted in `_matchkey` to a new Map i.e `rewardsMap`. After using `forEach` I'm trying `assign()` and `addAll()` methods but it is only adding one Map. The `_rewardMapList` will be updated dynamically on firebase.

What I'm trying: for each map in the _rewardMapList, extract the matchkey, Use the extracted matchkey as the key for rewardMap and assign all the maps in the _rewardMapList as value.

The code is as follows:

```
 final Map<String, RewardsModel> rewardsMap = {};

  void getRewardData() {
    _firebaseFirestore.collection('leagues').doc('pl').get().then(
      (ds) {
        var _mapData = ds.data();
        // Extracting the reward list of Maps
        List _rewardMapList = _mapData!['rewards'];
        _rewardMapList.forEach(
          (element) {
            // Extracting matchkey for each element
            final _matckkey = element['matchkey'];
            rewardsMap.addAll(
              {
                _matckkey: RewardsModel.fromMap(fieldData: element),
              },
            );
            // rewardsMap.assign(
            //   _matckkey,
            //   RewardsModel.fromMap(fieldData: element),
            // );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Reward Map Picture
[image]

Comment: I could not understand since it's hard by just guessing whats inside your map. Could you make a reproducible example using dartpad? That way would be easier to help you

Comment: Greetings @pedropimont I've updated the code. If still having difficulties I'll try updating dartpad. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've tried to understand what you need and I think you want to simply transform this `List` you have into some `Map`

See if it's that what you want, otherwise let me know.

You can paste it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)

```
    void main() {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _rewardMapList = [
    {
      'matchkey': 'RVM',
      't1goal': 1
    },
    {
      'matchkey': 'MVL',
      't1goal': 2,
    },
    {
      'matchkey': 'OOO',
      't1goal': 3,
    }
  ];

  final rewardsMap = Map<String, dynamic>.fromIterable(
    _rewardMapList,
    key: (e) => e['matchkey'],
    value: (_) => _rewardMapList,
  );

  print(rewardsMap);
}
```

Comment: No, it is still adding only one from the list of maps.

Comment: does this list repeats the key value?? If it does, it won't work, keys must be unique

Comment: Nope, it's only adding one Key: Value the first one. I want is for each map in the _rewardMapList extract the matchkey, Use the extracted matchkey as the key for rewardMap and assign all the maps in the _rewardMapList as value.

Comment: I've updated the answer, maybe that's what you want

Comment: Nope, The _rewardMapList will be dynamically updated in Firebase. It can be 3 or 4 or 10. The rewardMap takes String and Object Model. Map<String, RewardModel>();. Please check the image I've attached to the question. @pedro

Comment: Greeting Mr. Pedro, I solved the issue. The code I wrote was right but the fields weren't. The reason the map was storing only a single map was that the 2nd Maps i.e in Firebase field type did not match with the Model field type. I'm sorry for the trouble I caused. Thank you for your efforts. Cheers.  @pedro pimont

Comment: Glad you did it! thanks for letting me know @RajA